# Initialisation order throws null pointer on lazy val access

Tags: scala, initialization, lazy-evaluation

Expectedly, the following initialisation order without lazy val throws null pointer exception

```
class Foo {
  Bar.x // NullPointerException
}

object Bar extends Foo {
  val x = 42
}

object Hello extends App {
  Bar
}
```

Examining `-Xprint:jvm` output, and referencing @paradigmatic [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12185848/5205022),  we see this is due to `Foo`'s constructor running first and calling `Bar.x()` before `Bar.this.x` is initialised in `Bar`'s constructor:

```
  class Foo extends Object {
    def <init>(): example.Foo = {
      Foo.super.<init>();
      Bar.x();
      ()
    }
  };

  object Bar extends example.Foo {
    private[this] val x: Int = _;
    <stable> <accessor> def x(): Int = Bar.this.x;
    def <init>(): example.Bar.type = {
      Bar.super.<init>();
      Bar.this.x = 42;
      ()
    }
  };
```

However, why is null pointer also thrown when `x` is [lazy](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/initialization-order.html#use-lazy-vals) like so

```
object Bar extends Foo {
  lazy val x = 42
}
```

Analysing `-Xprint:jvm` output in lazy case we have

```
  class Foo extends Object {
    def <init>(): example.Foo = {
      Foo.super.<init>();
      Bar.x();
      ()
    }
  };
  object Bar extends example.Foo {
    final <synthetic> lazy private[this] var x: Int = _;
    @volatile private[this] var bitmap$0: Boolean = _;
    private def x$lzycompute(): Int = {
      Bar.this.synchronized(if (Bar.this.bitmap$0.unary_!())
        {
          Bar.this.x = (42: Int);
          Bar.this.bitmap$0 = true
        });
      Bar.this.x
    };
    <stable> <accessor> lazy def x(): Int = if (Bar.this.bitmap$0.unary_!())
      Bar.this.x$lzycompute()
    else
      Bar.this.x;
    def <init>(): example.Bar.type = {
      Bar.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  };
```

where it seems to me it should work due to the `bitmap$0` guard

```
    <stable> <accessor> lazy def x(): Int = if (Bar.this.bitmap$0.unary_!())
      Bar.this.x$lzycompute()
    else
      Bar.this.x;
```

Runtime field accessors check `-Xcheckinit` seems to be satisfied on my machine with Scala 2.12.8, so why `NullPointerException` when `lazy val x`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this NPE is related to `val` at all. Check this:

```
class Foo {
  Bar.anyMethod
}

object Bar extends Foo {
  def anyMethod = ???
}

object Hello extends App {
  Bar
}

//java.lang.NullPointerException
```

`Foo` is trying to run constructor on `Bar` while `Bar` is still under construction. So that's what your `Foo` is doing too before calling `x`.

Btw if you put everything into `Hello` with `main` method you will get StackOverflow instead of NPE in both mine and your cases.

```
object Hello {

   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

     class Foo {
       Bar.anyMethod
     }

     object Bar extends Foo { //<- Bar is like local val now instead of field 
       def anyMethod= ???     // of package object, so stack is available now.
     }

     Bar
   }

}
```

Comment: I cannot seem to replicate `StackOverflowError` in either case when putting everything in `Hello`, however it does throw NPE.

Comment: `StackOverflowError` is thrown only with `main` method. fixed that.

Comment: Seems strange calling child's constructor from parent's constructors cycle is legal. NPE being thrown in the first place instead of `StackOverflowError` is also confusing.

Comment: `NPE` instead of `StackOverflow` in first place is somehow related to the fact that there is no stack available at this point. Stack is available only inside methods.